# Azure Active Directory OIDC - IFrame Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am looking into Azure Active Directory OpenIDConnect authentication alongside an ASP.NET application, all of the quickstarts work very well when dealing with a self-hosted application and I am able to login correctly following their guides.

As part of the work I am looking at, there is a requirement to load my application inside an IFrame hosted in another application which is not in my control. This parent application will take care of the authentication of the user, and the IFrame version of my application will be expected to be utilising the same sign-on to access its content.

I cannot seem to see documentation regarding this on MSDN, has anyone any experience in that kind of setup? Will it even work?

I believe the domain of my application would need to be a sub-domain of the parent hosting application for the purpose of cookies, but will my application have access to cookies that are present in the parent applications interaction because that's how I believe it would know there is a logged-in context?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run an app on an iframe will be problematic because the Authorization Server will block requests via X-Frame-Options headers, which will be set to DENY by default.

If it was me I would tell stakeholders that using an iframe is a solution, not a requirement, and try to get to the underlying behaviour people are looking for.

These scenarios are often based around avoiding double logins, but sometimes a simple / standard solution such as this works best, and gets past all blocking issues and complexity:

- User signs in to App A and provides a credential
- User single signs on to App B very quickly

The standard option will be simple, future proof and extensible, whereas non standard options can add many hidden costs. If explained to stakeholders they may be happy with this type of solution.

**IFRAME LOGINS**

This is a matter of configuring the X-Frame-Options header to allow your web origin.It is a fairly common solution, but has potential security and portability issues.

Quite a few providers support iframe logins, but [from Googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246074/running-into-x-frame-options-issues-when-running-sample-azure-ad-b2c-auth-code/53246324#53246324) I suspect that Azure AD does not. If so then logins via popups are another option to consider.

**COOKIES AND USER GESTURES**

Another problem you are likely to run into is that browsers are increasingly dropping third party cookies these days. Using SSO cookies via full browser redirects works fine, but when issued via iframes and popups the browser is likely to drop them on subsequent requests.

**PROOF OF CONCEPT**

A good way forward is to develop a tiny app that uses Azure AD and iframes, to simulate your production setup. This should only take a few days and you can experiment with options until you find something that works and that your stakeholders are happy with.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, sadly the application delivery method (iFrame hosted inside a parent 'host') is locked in stone due to it being an existing system within their environment.

The iFrame application will run on the same domain as the parent host application, so I believe it would be able to read/respect SSO Cookies already in place (which were set when the user logged into the parent host application).

We have to ensure the iFramed content respects this SSO Cookie and is able to use the OIDC setup within .NET (classic, not .net core sadly) to log them in automatically.

Comment: OK - well I added some more notes and a possible direction for you - it may not be straightforward though ..